# pandas: Set zero values of rows to the max value of that row of dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a solution for modifying a dataframe using pandas. 
I have a dataframe like below which I need to change zero values of a row to maximum value of that row:

```
    a    b     c  
0   0    0  0.10        
1  2.1   0    0        
2   0  1.9    0        
3   0  7.8   6.5
```

should change to:

```
     a       b      c  
0   0.10    0.10   0.10        
1   2.1     2.1    2.1        
2   1.9     1.9    1.9        
3   7.8     7.8    7.8
```

Comment: last `6.5` is set to `7.8` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`DataFrame.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html):

```
df = df.mask(df == 0, df.max(axis=1), axis=0)
print (df)
     a    b    c
0  0.1  0.1  0.1
1  2.1  2.1  2.1
2  1.9  1.9  1.9
3  7.8  7.8  6.5
```

If want set all values by `max`:

```
arr = df.values.max(axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(arr[:, np.newaxis], len(df.columns), axis=1),
                  index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
     a    b    c
0  0.1  0.1  0.1
1  2.1  2.1  2.1
2  1.9  1.9  1.9
3  7.8  7.8  7.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the apply and replace function:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.replace(0, max(x)), axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
     a    b    c
0  0.1  0.1  0.1
1  2.1  2.1  2.1
2  1.9  1.9  1.9
3  7.8  7.8  6.5
```